# How can I get all entities without a specific related entity?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have these tables:

**users**

```
id 
name
```

**events**

```
id 
name
```

**entries**

```
id
user_id
event_id
```

How can I get all users that do not have an entry with `event_id` 4?

With this code:

```
 $users = User::query();
 $users->leftJoin('entries', 'users.id', '=', 'entries.user_id')
       ->where('event_id','!=', $event_id)->get();
```

I still get users that already have an entry for that specific event.

This is what I want:

- Get all entries which have event_id 4
- Get the user_id from those entries
- Remove other entries which have that user_id.

---

```
$entries = Entry::where(event_id, '=', 4)->get();

foreach ($entries as &$entry) {
    //remove all entries from $entries array which "user_id = $entry->user_id"
}
```

How can I do the above with just a query?

Comment: did you create all the relationships between the models?

Comment: Yes, but i dont want use the With method.

Comment: Why you don't want to use with method? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Going by your question following is the answer but i guess this is not what you finally want. so elaborate more and specify the sample input and output datasets

```
select * from your_table where event_id <> 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you want is:

```
select user_id
from t 
group by user_id
having sum(event_id = 4) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.*
  from User u
  left join entries e
  on e.user_id = u.id and e.event_id = 4
  where e.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `<>`, not `!=`. Also you're not letting it know which  table `event_id` is on.

Try

```
 $users = User::query();
 $users->leftJoin('entries', 'users.id', '=', 'entries.user_id')
       ->where('entries.event_id','<>', $event_id)->get();
```

More information can be found at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

Comment: `<>` and `!=` have the same functionality across most databases, and more specifically in `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`whereDoesntHave`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereDoesntHave) builder method.

```
$users = User::query()->whereDoesntHave("entry", function($q) use ($event_id) {
    $q->where('id', $event_id);
})->get();
```

The method takes a closure in which you can define criteria for the related entities that must not exist.

---

If you need the users and the entries, I think you can still join the entries using `with`.

```
$users = User::query()
    ->with('entries')
    ->whereDoesntHave("entry", function($q) use ($event_id) {
        $q->where('id', $event_id); })
    ->get();
```